# When I add a CEWP my columns titles are condensing

Tags: 2013, jquery, form, cewp

I am following [these steps](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/jquery-to-the-rescue-labeled-sections-on-default-forms.aspx) to create a label on my SP new form. When i add the CEWP and insert the code snippet that is provided in the instructions my title columns condense and go from looking like this [image] to looking like this. [image]
If any one could help in solving this issue it would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at line 5 in his code, he's removing the property for line wraps, rather, removing the stopping of the line breaks, thus allowing line breaks:

`$("nobr").css("white-space","normal"); // Lets labels wrap`

Remove that and that should help.